# Creating a network flow model for building a new organizing schema for a departament

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, bipartite-graphs, network-flow

The problem I'm attempting to solve is formulated like this: 
A department consists of *n* groups such as for each group *i* in $\overline{1,n}$ contains $p_i$ members. 
A change in the organization is wanted so that:

- the new organizing schema contains *q* groups of members
- each group in $\overline{1,q}$ will contain $k_i$ members
- the new groups may not contain more than *c* members which were part of the same old group (c $\geq$ 2 , c $\in \mathbb{N}$)

How to find a model based on a flow network to build this new organizing schema? 
I've tried building a network flow graph but I had trouble in representing the member groups and the restriction that no more than *c* members which were part of an old group can be present in a new group. Thank you for reading the question, any hint or solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you please edit your post to say a little more about what you have tried? That will help attract more attention to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll repeat my answer from [this deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3966842/create-a-graph-network-flow-model-for-the-computer-science-department) from another user earlier today:

Define a complete bipartite graph with $n$ supply nodes and $q$ demand nodes. The flow from node $i$ to node $j$ indicates the number of students that move from old group $i$ to new group $j$. Each flow variable has an upper bound of $c$.